# How to source ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu Core via ssh?

Tags: ros, source, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am having a small issue sourcing ROS kinectic in my Raspberry PI 3(OS: Ubuntu Core). Every time I want to use ROS i have to use the command `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then I can use ROS commands like `roscore`. But I want to source ROS kinectic in the bash file. I have tried `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` but doesnt source ROS automatically. Is there another way to source it in the bash file?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288684/how-to-source-ros-kinetic-in-ubuntu-core-via-ssh?/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, logins over SSH are treated differently from regular logins, hence `.bashrc` is not being evaluated, and thus your `source` line isn't executed.

If you search Google for this you're bound to find many hints.

> I have tried `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` [..]

Why the `sudo`? Are you running things as root?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-04-15**:
found it thanks! Doing

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

also sudo because i figured we might be superuser